# How to keep text in the middle of the screen even when re-sizing page in html/css

Tags: html, css

When ever i re size my website in my browser my text gets cut off. 
Here are some pictures that should help~
Before Re-sizing

http://puu.sh/d3au0/9ec512d685.png

After Re-sizing

http://puu.sh/d3aAx/fbd2ccfb31.png

Here is my code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="content">
        <p>this is sample text.this is sample text.this is sample text.this is sample text.this      is sample text.</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.content {
position: relative;
text-align: center;
padding-left: 450px;
padding-right: 450px;
width: 800px;
top: 50px;
font-size: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `padding` and add `margin: 0 auto`.

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n6ty853d/)

```css
.content {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  width: 800px;
  top: 50px;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <p>this is sample text.this is sample text.this is sample text.this is sample text.this is sample text.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.content {
padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
display: inline;
width: 800px;
font-size: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Hiya, this may well solve the problem... but it'd be good if you could edit your answer and provide a little explanation about how and why it works :) Don't forget - there are heaps of newbies on Stack overflow, and they could learn a thing or two from your expertise - what's obvious to you might not be so to them.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this...

```
.content {
width: 560px //change it as per your requirements
display:block;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
font-size: 20px;
}
```